Multiple IDS not hitting redirect controller action method in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC
I am using multiple IDP in ASP.NET Core MVC using Microsoft.Identity.Ui & Web packages for SSO.
I am able to sign-in with two IDPS but after sign-in Azure b2c and Azure AD service both are not hitting my controller.
Here is my startup:
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();

services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>{// This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax;options.HttpOnly = Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.HttpOnlyPolicy.None;options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();});

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => { options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie"; });

services.AddSession(options => {});

services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("Internal"), "Internal", null).EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi: Scopes")?.Split(' ')).AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>("Internal", options =>
                {
                    //var existingOnTokenValidatedHandler = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;
                    //options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                    //{
                    //    await existingOnTokenValidatedHandler(context);
    
                    //    if (context.Principal != null)
                    //    {
                    //        await context.HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                    //            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, context.Principal);
                    //    }
                    //};
                });
    
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(
                            Configuration.GetSection("External"), "External", null)
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamB2CApi:Scope")?.Split(' '))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
                    services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>("External", options =>
                    {
                        options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
                        //options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                        //var existingOnTokenValidatedHandler = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;
                        //options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                        //{
                        //    await existingOnTokenValidatedHandler(context);
    
                        //    if (context.Principal != null)
                        //    {
                        //        await context.HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                        //            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, context.Principal);
                        //    }
                        //};
                    });
            services.Configure<ReverseProxyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("ReverseProxy"));

My controller where using to set claims:
public ActionResult GetExternalToken()
{
}

public ActionResult GetInternalToken() 
{
}

This above is not invoking after redirect from azure b2c & azure ad service post back,

It should hit this method after signin from Azure b2c
